# Tweak DLL module name during LoadLibrary

Tags: c++, loadlibrary, dll, portable-executable

I want to load at runtime a third party binary plug-in (P.dll) in my application (A.exe). This plug-in has been built for another application (B.exe).

The plug-in has implicit dll import on the B.exe module, like :

- Module Name : B.exe
- func1
- func2
- func3

I have exported the functions func1, func2 and func3 from A.exe but I can't load the dll with `LoadLibrary` because there is no module named "B.exe".

Is there something better to do than renaming my application "B.exe" or patching P.dll's PE ?

Thanks,

Cyril

Comment: This is *very* unusual, do double-check with dumpbin.exe /imports.  You're pretty stuck if this is real.

Comment: How does P.dll refer to B.exe exactly? It seems strange to me that a dll refers to an exe by name. B.exe is intended to use P.dll, and not vice versa...

Comment: What happens if you rename A.exe to B.exe? Can it really load P.dll?

Comment: Hans : i've just double-checked with dumpbin, and yes the dll has implicit imports on the exe.

Comment: Kol : it is legal to export symbols from an exe. You can even generate a .lib file.

Comment: Kol : yes if I rename it, it works.

Comment: Renaming your application is the only supported mechanism.

Comment: Wow, this issue has really earned the dll-hell tag.

Answer (score 1):

You can create fake B.exe, (actually it can be DLL), and redirect B.exe exports to A.exe .

Redirecting can be done by forwarding exports, see "Export Forwarding" section [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc301808.aspx).

Comment: Add a DLL called B.dll - can be compiled from a module file no code is required. Define redirects using the module file to redirect the imports to A.exe. Rename B.DLL to B.EXE. In A.exe, load B.EXE using `LoadLibrary()`. Then load P.dll and the imports should resolve. This works because DLLs don't *have* to be called `*.dll` they can be called anything.